# How to detect application launch type (auto-start or manual)?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How can I detect that application was automatically started (auto-start when device turned on) or user has started it manually (from Programs etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hint:
You can use Arguments to distinguish between both, and put those arguments in the shortcut.
check [Command Line Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96s74eb0.aspx) to know how to use arguments, and in the shortcut write

```
path\executable.exe autostart
```

for the shortcut in startup folder, after that in your application check this...

**EDIT1:**
the path in windows mobile start from \ this is the root, now to get the startup folder
you can write:

```
\widnows\startup
```

and the complete path will be

```
\widnows\startup\executable.exe autostart
```

**Edit2**:
Open the setup project, right click on "file system and target machine, then "Add Special Folder" then choose "startup Folder", after that put your shortcut with arguments there...

**Edit3:**

you are right, there is no place to put arguments, so we should create the shortcut manually:

1- create text file and change the extension to be lnk

2- edit the file by drag& drop it to notepad, and write inside it the following line:

```
43#"\widnows\startup\executable.exe autostart"
```

3- take care about the first number, it's the character count after the #, if you change the path so you should recalculate the character count again and put it in the first.
4- add this file to the start up folder in VS....

Comment: Where can I specify this. When I created installer for application, I am telling installer to make this application auto-start. As in windows, we specify in "Environment Variables", how can I add arguments to my application in Windows-Mobile 6.1?

Comment: I don't see any option to put shortcut with arguments. How can I specify that to run this shortcut with such such arguments?

Comment: Thanks! it works in that way! at the same time I found same solution at: http://www.johandekoning.nl/index.php/2008/08/04/command-line-arguments-windows-mobile/

Comment: Wael, a small correction in your code that is; argument 'autostart' will come outside quotations, so it will become like this:

43#"\widnows\startup\executable.exe" autostart